# How to write javascript code using external files only

Tags: javascript, html5boilerplate

When using HTML5 Boilerplate, you are given a script.js file and the jquery file are all loaded after the body.

How do I know when to call certain code for a specific page? For eg. What if on `/maps` I want to load google maps dynamically, how do I accomplish this without putting it on the page and using `script.js` file while having it not load the map for all pages?

Basically, how do I structure my code when I can't have any script in my pages? How do I know what code to call for a particular page?

Answer (score 0):

Script files that are included are immediately executed, so inside the script file you could have a section check the URL of the page you're on.

For example, something like this:

```
if (window.location.href === "http://myapp.com/maps") {
   // call the map function or whatever ...
}
```

But, out of curiosity, why can't you add a script file to the specific page you're on? I'd only recommend the solution above if you absolutely cannot edit the HTML of your pages.

Comment: using mvc with routing, urls may change, I'll have to go through and change all of these :(

Comment: To answer your question, the way boilerplate set it up is that the script file is loaded at the bottom of the body tag. When using mvc or other frameworks, you normally just have that as your layout template

Comment: You could also use a regular expression to search instead of a straight up match if you need some flexibility.

Comment: If you're using an MVC framework, you could insert script tags into the view files.

Comment: That will execute jquery code before jquery is loaded since he loads that at the end of the body tag too. Or should I just put jquery in the header?

Comment: What framework? Most frameworks allow you to insert content anywhere. You could put a hook in the layout template after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: asp.net mvc, could you give an example of that hook?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with asp.net. You could ask that as another question and I'm sure someone else will know the answer, but I'd definitely recommend doing that rather than using Javascript to figure out what page you're on.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same question. I searched and just found these two

http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

http://www.viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

I am going through of this, and not yet completely reviewed. See if it is useful to you in between.